# Cannot Open Python Shelve Object

Tags: python-2.7, shelve

Running into a LOT of problems trying to use shelve(s) in Python.

I was able to create a new shelf *.dbm object just fine moments ago, but now, I am getting an error:

```
import shelve
TESTING = shelve.open('C:\Users\dtruman\Documents\PROJECTS\testing.dbm','c',writeback=True)
```

Python returns the following cryptic error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    TESTING = shelve.open('C:\Users\dtruman\Documents\PROJECTS\testing.dbm','c',writeback=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python_2-7-11\lib\shelve.py", line 243, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python_2-7-11\lib\shelve.py", line 227, in __init__
Shelf.__init__(self, anydbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python_2-7-11\lib\anydbm.py", line 85, in open
return mod.open(file, flag, mode)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python_2-7-11\lib\dbhash.py", line 18, in open
return bsddb.hashopen(file, flag, mode)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python_2-7-11\lib\bsddb\__init__.py", line 364, in hashopen
d.open(file, db.DB_HASH, flags, mode)
DBError: (14, 'Bad address')
```

It seems like I am trying to perform a very straightforward operation, but Python is not liking it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The "\t" in that filepath string is probably being interpreted as a tab. Try making the filepath a raw string:

```
TESTING = shelve.open(r'C:\Users\dtruman\Documents\PROJECTS\testing.dbm','c',writeback=True)
```